# Balanced Mono XLR output to Unbalanced Stereo Input

Tags: audio, stereo, balanced, unbalanced, xlr

I have an Allen & Heath ZED-10 mixer with a balanced XLR output. All signals coming into this mixer are mono and therefore we were going to use a single balanced mono XLR main output (Left channel). This output is going to a camera 75ft away via balanced XLR cable. However, the camera has a stereo (unbalanced) 1/8" (3.5mm) input.

What is the best way to convert this signal? I want to maintain the balanced XLR cable as far to the camera as possible to reduce interference and just adapt at the camera if possible, but I'm not sure if that's feasible. I found the Whirlwind ISOPOD line level summing balancer, but that says it takes a stereo INPUT and changes it to a balanced mono OUTPUT. I'm not sure if that's a bi-directional device or not.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Just buy an adapter

Comment: @Justme My understanding is that an XLR to 1/8" stereo adapter will give me the same signal on Left/Right channels, but with opposite polarity (because it's just mapping the 2 balanced signals to the 2 channels) which results in a weird "hollow" sound.

Comment: Well get the right adapter then, not the wrong kind you don't want. The one that has unbalanced output. You may need two adapters, one to convert a single balanced XLR to single unbalanced anything, like RCA. Then maybe a RCA splitter to two RCAs. And then RCA to 3.5mm TRS.

Comment: There are devices designed to do this, they are called DI boxes, they come as active or passive. Using a passive (Generally a transformer) should do just great.